# Legend: change of fill color R plot

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I could change the **fill color** of the **square** next to **beta** in my **legend below** to be according to: `adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=0.05)`?

Here is my **current R code** (with no success):

```
curve(dt(x,19),-5,5)

legend("topright",legend=c(expression(paste("Power")),expression(paste(beta))),
density=c(15,0),angle=140,fill=T,col=c(adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=0.05),0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
legend("topright",legend=c(expression(paste("Power")),expression(paste(beta))),
       density=c(15,0),angle=140,fill=T,border=c('black', 'blue'))
```

[image]

**[EDITED]**

```
legend("topright",legend=c(expression(paste("Power")),expression(paste(beta))),
       density=c(15,NA),angle=140,fill=c("#000000FF", adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=0.5)),
       border=c("#000000FF", adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=0.5)))
```

[image]